# Setting one instance of a graph to zoom in the x direction only

Tags: matlab, oop, graph, zooming

I have a figure containing three instances of a graph plotting class. I want two of them to be able to zoom in/out in both the x and y direction, and one of the instances to be able to zoom in only the x direction. At the moment I can set the graphs to be able to zoom using

```
zoom(obj.Axes, 'on')
```

And this allows for zooming in both x and y directions. I want to be able to change the zoom characteristics of one of the graphs using a conditional statement, within the graph plotting class, like this

```
if strcmp(obj.Type, "Axes3") % obj.Type is a descriptor, set when the instances are created, that I am using to
                             % differentiate between the graphs, for the other two graphs these would be
                             % "Axes1" and "Axes2"
    zoom(obj.Axes, 'xon');
    title(obj.Axes, "Graph 3");
else
    zoom(obj.Axes, 'on');
    title(obj.Axes, "Other Graphs");
end
```

However when I implement this all three of the graphs are set to zoom in only the x direction. I think it may be a result of the zoom() function setting the zoom properties for all the graphs in the same figure, not just the one instance. What is confusing me though is that the title function is successfully setting the titles differently for each graph, same goes for xlabel and ylabel which I have left out here but are implemented the same way as title.

Any ideas about how to set the zoom property of each graph independently?

Comment: You first have to make a zoom object `z = zoom();`, and then you can set if for individual axes with `setAxesZoomConstraint(z, obj.Axes, 'xy')`;

Comment: Thanks that seems to have solved the issue!